# Loopback - Model's ACL list to looup in database and not in its json file

Tags: node.js, acl, loopbackjs, node-modules

I am new to the loopback framework in node.js.

In My project, I can create Models, and extend built-in models and apply acls on it. Everything was fine.

But, I could not see the ACL list which I applied for my models in my Database table 'ACL'.

The ACL list applied for models via `<model>.json` is working fine. But i need to apply via **my Database**.

**To Achieve:** Since, from UI (client side), I am going to allow super admin to ***customize the properties for specific roles***. And i planned to update these property Role's in ACL table. For this reason, I need the ACL list for model's to be viewed from DB instead of `<model>.json` file.

```
ACL Table columns:
- id
- model
- principalId
- property
- accessType
- permission
- principalType
```

- And, based on the acl array in .json, will it update the corresponding ACL table in DB ?

(or)

- We have to manually update DB (ACL table) ?

Also, i looked for a solution from [here](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/2830) but no luck.
Please Help me to achieve this... (Synchronising ACL list of models with Database ACL table)
Correct me if i am wrong anywhere.

Thankyou.

Answer (score 1):

The link you posted links to [another post](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/2055#issuecomment-182171119) which explains how to modify model ACLs at runtime.

> It isn't enough to create ACLs you have to attach them to to the models themselves using

```
MyModel.settings.acls.push(...)
```

It even provides a remote method which shows you how to add an ACL to a model

```
MyModel.aclsPost = function (acl, context, cb) {
        MyModel.settings.acls.push(acl);
        cb(null, {});
    }

    MyModel.remoteMethod(
        'aclsPost',
        {
            accepts: [
                {arg: 'acl', type: 'Object', http: {source: 'body'}},
                {arg: 'context', type: 'object', http: {source: 'context'}}
            ],
            http: {path: '/acls', verb: 'post', status: 201, errorStatus: 404}
        }
);
```